# It is possible to show a weekNumber in Kendo UI Angular DatePicker

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2

In the MVC and the jQuery Version of Kendo's DatePicker it's possible to show the weekNumber as a column in the DatePicker.

How can I enable this feature in the Angular 2 - Edition of the component? Things like [weekNumber]="true" doesn't work.

jQuery - Edition:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#configuration-weekNumber

Answer (score 0):

Right now, Kendo Calendar for Angular doesn't support week numbers. There is no feasible workaround that we can think of as the week numbers are part of the internal view that renders the month days.

As far as I know, it is final development stage and pretty soon it should be released as `@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs@dev` package. I suppose this will happen within a week or so.